# The method decodeBase64(byte[]) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, jsp

Upgraded from Java 1.6.2 to Java 1.7.25 and now on my JSP upon compiling I am getting the following:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path 
>       [/dswsbobje] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: encrypt.jsp
>       The method decodeBase64(byte[]) in the type Base64 is not applicable for 
>       the arguments (String)
>
> 40:byte[] raw = Base64.decodeBase64(secret64);
>
> An error occurred at line: 47 in the jsp file: encrypt.jsp
>       The method encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[]) is undefined for the type 
>       Base64
>
> 47:out.write ("**User Name " + userid + ":** " + 
>       Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(cipher.doFinal(userid.getBytes())));

What is causing these errors and how do I resolve them?

Comment: Which `Base64` class is that?

Comment: If you just upgraded to Java 7, why did you upgrade to the very old `u25` version when `u79` is the latest? And why do you think upgrading Java has any impact on the `Base64` class, whichever it is, what is not from the Java Runtime Library?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the class `Base64` you're using was changed from one version to the other. You haven't provided the complete classname of this class but Google tells me that it should be Apache Commons Codec with version >= 1.4.

It seems that you somehow are now using an older version of this library, because the methods the compiler complains about are added with version 1.4, so if you now use an older one, the methods can't be found.

Replace the older library by a more recent one should fix your problem. Alternatively you can change the calls of the methods to ones that already existed in older versions, e.g.

```
byte[] raw = Base64.decodeBase64(secret64);
```

to

```
byte[] raw = Base64.decodeBase64(secret64.getBytes(charset));
```

and

```
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(cipher.doFinal(userid.getBytes())));
```

to

```
new String(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(cipher.doFinal(userid.getBytes(charset)))), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: using these imports: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec"%>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.Cipher"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*"%>                      version 1.4 on the common.codec, Reason for the version is because it is in a Business Objects 4.1 installation where the Tomcat is stalled (7.0.55).

Comment: @Mr.St33l As I said, the methods should exist in 1.4 but if there is another commons-codec jar in the classpath that is older, you will have this effect.

Comment: Where do I look for the classpath?

Comment: @Mr.St33l `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))` prints the system's classpath on STDOUT. If your JSP page is part of a web application, there might be a differing classpath. Have a look at the web servers management console (I don't know Tomcat well enough to tell you the required clicks) where you should find the classpath for each web app.

Comment: This is what shows in my CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\sapjvm\lib\tools.jar

Comment: Would it be in any of those .jar files? Or in the path of those .jar files?